# How could i get access in Jenkins to Local Files or Files on a Network-Directory?

Tags: shell, jenkins, upload, jenkins-pipeline, file-transfer

I am kinda new to Jenkins and need some help. I am thankful for any Information or Website anyone could help me with.
On my Jenkins Pipeline, I have to get access to files on a Network-directory (Windows-Server).
Jenkins is running on Linux. What would be the best and easiest solution to load the files from localdir or networkdir to my Jenkins-Workspace?

Comment: Jenkins steps that work directly with files (such as `readFile`) can only access files in the workspace. To copy files from network locations, use shell commands (e. g. by using [`sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) step).

Comment: Ok ty gona try shell with sftp.